# C - Error on free()?

Tags: c

I am making some hash function.

It's source code is ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int m_hash(char *input, size_t in_length, char *output, size_t out_length);

int main()
{
    char buffer[1025];
    char output[65];
    output[64] = '\0';
    while(1)
    {
        printf("enter what will hash : ");
        fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);
        buffer[1024] = '\0';
        m_hash(buffer, strlen(buffer), output, 64);
        printf("your string (hashed) : %s\n", output);
    }
    return 0;
}

int m_hash(char *input, size_t in_length, char *output, size_t out_length) // 0 on Success, 1 on Fail.
{
    const char OUT[64] = "zxcvbnmasdfghjklqwertyuiopZXCVBNMASDFGHJKLQWERTYUIOP1234567890_-";
    char *snow = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * out_length);
    if (snow == NULL) return 1;
    int *out = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * out_length);
    if (out == NULL)
    {
        free(snow);
        return 1;
    }
    memset(out, 0x00, sizeof(int) * out_length);
    size_t tmp = 0, i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < out_length; i++)
    {
        tmp += i * i;
        snow[i] = tmp / (i + 1);
        tmp -= snow[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < in_length; i++)
    {
        out[((tmp *= (i + 1)) % out_length + out_length) % out_length] += input[i];
        snow[i] += input[i];
        for (j = 0; j < out_length; j++)
        {
            out[((i + j) % out_length + out_length) % out_length] += snow[j] % (i + 1);
        }
    }
printf("Will free snow.\n");
    free(snow); // ERROR WTF?
printf("Freed snow.\n");
    for (i = 0; i < out_length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = OUT[(out[i] % 64 + 64) % 64];
    }
    free(out);
    return 0;
}
```

When I enter short string, there is no error. But when I enter long string like this...
[It's seems to free() makes error...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ536.png)
There is error on 'free(snow);'?!?!!

Visual studio's debug message is...
    HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#92) at 0x01505D08.
    CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

I really don't know what's wrong with this...

What's wrong...? ㅠ.ㅜ

Comment: Question: How do you plan to break out of the `while(1)` loop?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: @SouravGhosh The program is not finished yet... I will add break :D :D

Comment: If `in_length > out_length` the code `snow[i] += input[i];` access `snow` out of bounds.

Comment: `out[((tmp *= (i + 1)) % out_length + out_length) % out_length] += input[i];`..seriously?? and you expect ___people___ to read your code?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Oh... Sorry T.T I didn't think it...

Comment: @LPs omg... I can't understand why I haven't seen it... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without debugging the exact place where it happens -> at some point you're writing before/after the memory you allocated. This overwrites the allocation metadata which doesn't affect your program while it's running, but when you try to free the memory, you'll find garbage and crash.

If you were running linux I'd recommend trying `valgrind` to debug this, but apparently there are some Windows options as well: [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

Basically you want something which will error out the moment you write out of bounds, not when you try to read it back.

Comment: With all due respect, this is more suitable as a comment.

Comment: @SouravGhosh It's too long for a comment and it answers the question. As you mentioned yourself - was anybody expected to actually read that code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the insufficient malloc'd `snow` buffer.
You malloc it the size out_length (`char *snow = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * out_length);`).

Though you loop over it with in_length (wich is up to 1024 while out_length is 64):

```
for (i = 0; i < in_length; i++)
{
    out[((tmp *= (i + 1)) % out_length + out_length) % out_length] += input[i];
    snow[i] += input[i];
    for (j = 0; j < out_length; j++)
    {
        out[((i + j) % out_length + out_length) % out_length] += snow[j] % (i + 1);
    }
}
```

At the third line of this block, when i > 64, you get a memory error most likely causing a memory corruption making your program crash at `free()`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by the comments above, there would be a greater possibility that `in_length > out_length`. Which also supports your facts that it will crash for very long strings.

So with that, you may want to support increasing the size of `snow` via realloc prior to `for (i = 0; i < in_length; i++)`

```
if (in_length > out_length) {
    int additional_bytes =  in_length - out_length;
    snow = realloc(snow, sizeof(char) * (out_length + additional_bytes));
}
```